# Pass a dynamic ip of a service as environment variable in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, ip

So I'm trying to connect two docker services in docker-compose. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111010/docker-compose-pass-ip-of-services) question but it doesn't work for me. I print the env variable in my code and it's just displays 'mariadb' somewhy. It works for PMA but not for my custom app. How can I use it properly?

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        environment:
          MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

    myproject:
      build: .
      environment:
        - DBHOST=mariadb
      depends_on:
        - mariadb
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "8000:80"
        environment:
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
          - PMA_HOST=mariadb
        depends_on: 
            - mariadb
                   
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

Log:

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'mariadb' (OS Error: System error, errno = -11)
```

I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1) package.

The build is just a simple dart dockerfile as in [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/dart).

This is how I want to connect:

````dart
final settings = ConnectionSettings(host: 'mariadb',user: 'root',password: EnvStore.dbpass);
    conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
    ```
````

Comment: Actually wht you want to do?

Comment: I want to connect to mariadb. I'm using dart for this and I don't want to give a static IP for mariadb if it's not necessery

Comment: If it display marisdb it is correct because docker compose resolve it  when you want to connect. Can you add the db url to the post.

Comment: What is in your image?  Within that Compose file I would expect the host name `mariadb` to reach your database.

Comment: I tried to use "mariadb" as host but it doesn't work:
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'mariadb' (OS Error: System error, errno = -11)